# Can I safely remove the Amazon EC2 ssh key?

Tags: ssh

In my authorized_keys file, I have two public keys. "evb_aws" and my own. I'm guessing the first one is for Amazon to be able to get access to the instance. Can I safely get rid of it?

I'm pretty sure there'll be some answers saying "why?" - that's not the question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

We do this and have had no problems. There's nothing in Amazon's terms of service at http://aws.amazon.com/agreement/ that indicate that you have to provide them a login to your box (and in many cases that would be a violation of your data security obligations)

What AMI are you using? I've not noticed another key aside from mine being installed.